# which blog software manages multiple language posts, modular privacy, and custom RSS syndication?

Tags: rss, openid, blogs, multilingual, privacy

I'm considering which software to use for a blog that I would like to install in a personal home server (synology). Here are my requirements:

- **Language management**: I'll be writing in different languages, and some entries would be translated in different languages, not always the same. Blog readers should be able to select which languages they can/wish to read. For instance, if they chose English, then all entries which have English translation would appear in English, the remaining appearing in whatever language they were written, or not at all.
- **RSS customization**: the blog will broach different subjects. I would like the users to be able to customize a RSS syndication which corresponds to their interests, so that the sigal to noise ration in their RSS readers remains bearable. This should probably work with a "Categoriy" or "Tag" system.
- **sub-blogs**: I would like to have sub-blogs with their own url, which would present a subset of the blog entries. For instance my blog could deal with politics, sports, and myLife, and I could produce the following blog urls: blog.mydomain.tld (shows everything), opinions.mydomain.tld (shows only the politics related posts), sports.mydomain.tld (all entries dedicated to sports). I would also like to theme differently those sub-blogs (i.e. a ball picture for sports.mydomain.tld, etc).
- **modular privacy**: my intended audience is heterogeneous (family, sets of friends, the internet), and I would like to be able to limit access to certain entries to different subsets of users. To me, the most obvious way to do this would be to define users with a login and password. I would then pool them into groups, and define for each entry if it is private, and if so which groups can read it. I do not necessarily want to share the same things between my neighbors and my school friends.

That also brings the issue of RSS syndication: either each user would have its how RSS thread, or then RSS could be category specific and the private entries would appear without content. Perhaps other possibilities exist.

These set of features are quite specific. I was thinking of using a blog software to implement them, but perhaps I'm thinking this wrong and I should use a CMS or even a framework?

Another point is that this is done for "fun", and although I can program (python, etc), this is not my day job, so it should not require expert level skills or full time investment to implement. A solution which involves me developing a whole new blog application is not adapted to my constraints.

**EDIT**

- **OpenID**: I like the Stack Overflow login system (check this [screen capture of it](http://nsa20.casimages.com/img/2010/12/19/101219101041560868.png)), because most readers already have an OpenID, and in any case do not need to create a specific one for my blog. The system I would use should be capable of using the OpenID method of authentication

Comment: Which have you looked at? This request sounds like a portal / CMS implementation rather than a 'blog'

Comment: I've checked DotClear, it has multilingual posts, sub-blogs and RSS customization, but no modular privacy. I'm trying to find out whether wordpress fits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the best translation software around.
But I only use a Babylon Software as an Online Translator too.
You can find it at http://babylon.depapaz.com
Till now, I only use this program for my online translation software.
And I think is good enough as a Translation Software.